# how to read input files taken as parameters in C++

Tags: c++, input

I've just practiced coding C++. I knew in Java, we could have a public main method, which could read input file names as parameters of the string array argument. But I wonder how I do the same task in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Java and C++ follow the same C-like syntax. So it doesn't really differ from what you had in Java. In Java you had a string class :

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
      System.out.println("Argument " + i + " = " + args[i]);
  }
}
```

C/C++ mostly use primitive character arrays in order to store strings. Although Standard Template Library also provides string classes, but C++ uses native char arrays to store commandline arguments. The main function takes two variables :

int argc : number of commandline arguments
char *argv[] : an array of character strings

You can also say it can be written as char **argv, because of the underlying representation of two dimensional arrays in C/C++, but both mean the same thing. The equivalent of the above code in C++ would be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    std::cout << "Argument " << i << " = "
         << argv[i] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it the same way, with slightly different syntax because C arrays do not store their length, so it is passed as a separate parameter.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Read args from argv, up to argc args.
    // argv[0] is the name of the program
    // argv[1] is the first argument
}
```

Comment: @goldbergski because each argument requires a `char*`, so to point to an array of `char*` you need `char**`.

Answer (score 0):

The `main` function gives you the argument count and the actual arguments as an array of character arrays.

To safely work with this, you should first turn this information into a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> arguments;
    for (int index = 0; index < argc; ++index) {
        arguments.push_back(argv[index]);
    }
}
```

You will notice that `arguments[0]` is equal to the filename of the executable (in theory, this depends on the system you're using). If you are on Windows and have an executable called `stackoverflow.exe`, then starting it with

```
stackoverflow.exe one two
```

would result in `arguments` containing `{ "stackoverflow.exe"`, `"one"`, `"two" }`.